# Get type of selectedItem in hierarchical treeview

Tags: c#, xaml, treeview

I have a hierarchical treeview with multiple types of items bound to different levels.  I need to know what type of item is selected. The type of item will determine the visibility of menus elsewhere in the application.

I understand that I can't give a hierarchical item a name, otherwise this would be ideal.

Hierarchical treeview:

```
<TreeView x:Name="MainTreeView">
    <TreeViewItem x:Name="RobotTreeViewItemOwner" Header="Robots" ItemsSource="{Binding Robots}">
        <TreeViewItem.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Robot}" ItemsSource="{Binding Processes}">
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem x:Name="BookTreeViewItemOwner" Header="Books" ItemsSource="{Binding Books}">
        <TreeViewItem.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Book}" ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}">
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

The following code binds one level higher than I'm looking for. Is there a way to replicate this for the actual Robot or Book items?

```
<MenuItem DataContext="{Binding ElementName=BookTreeViewItemOwner}" Header="Print Book" Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource IsBook}}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to SelectedItem at the root of the Treeview and use a converter to check for the correct type.

```
<MenuItem Header="Print Book" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MainTreeView, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource IsBookSelectedConverter}}"/>
```

Snippet for the converter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is Book)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by listening to the SelectedItemChanged event of the TreeView (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditemchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
private void SelectionChanged(object sender,    RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Object> e)
{
    TreeViewItem selectedItem =e.NewValue as TreeViewItem
    // Inspect to get the type of the selected item and update your menus
}
```

This would allow you to programmatically make the calls to set menu visibility as needed.

Comment: Agreed, and that was my initial workaround.  However that adds quite a bit of extra logic. That logic would go into the codebehind, which as a general principle is to be avoided.